# How do I cancel the animation on a view property in an Animatable view?

Tags: animation, swiftui

I have a progress-indicator view, on which I want to be able to animate the current progress level from parent views. So, following the same pattern I see in all examples, I have the progress control written as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CircularProgressView: View, Animatable
{
    var         percentComplete: Float
    @State var  FGColor: Color
    @State var  BGColor: Color

    var         animatableData: Float
    {
        get
        {
            return percentComplete
        }
        set
        {
            percentComplete = newValue
        }
    }

    init(foregroundColor: Color, backgroundColor: Color = Color.clear, percentComplete: Float)
    {
        FGColor = foregroundColor
        BGColor = backgroundColor
        self.percentComplete = percentComplete
        print("Progress control init with \(percentComplete) %")
    }

    var body: some View
    {
        Text("progressControl internal percent: \(percentComplete)")
        ZStack
        {
            Circle()
            .stroke(
                BGColor.opacity(0.5),
                lineWidth: 30
            )

            Circle()
            .trim(from: 0, to: CGFloat(percentComplete / 100))
            .stroke(
                FGColor,
                lineWidth: 30
            )
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
        }
    }
}
```

If you put it into another view and attempt to use its animatable progress as follows:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View
{
    @State var progressStarted: Bool = false

    var body: some View
    {
        VStack
        {
            CircularProgressView(foregroundColor: Color.red, percentComplete: progressStarted ? 100 : 0)
                .animation(.linear(duration: 5), value: progressStarted)

            Text("Progress is \(progressStarted ? "started" : "stopped")")
            Button(action: {progressStarted.toggle()}, label: {
                Text("Toggle progress")
            })
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

you'll find that it doesn't immediately update on a change to the animatable value... but logically I guess that's correct. It seems that a curve is being loaded into the view for the animatable value, and any subsequent change just appends more animation to the curve. Logical, but it cripples the intended function of this control. How does one overcome this problem in general, for views on which you've exposed animatable properties?

[Screen grab of the behavior here](https://youtube.com/shorts/_d0JGUNt4_Q).

[Downloadable project here](https://drive.usercontent.google.com/download?id=1LjX2hUQ-PHjP1edaM7p0obccfxoQkGOU&export=download).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is causes by SwiftUI running both animations (0 to 100 and 100 to 0) at the same time. SwiftUI combines these in its own way, and the period where both animations are running is non-linear. This is the default behaviour. See also [the WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10156) talking about this.

If you just want to cancel the animation and set `percentComplete` to 0 immediately without animation, you can use an animation that immediately finishes like this:

```
struct Cancel: CustomAnimation {
    
    func animate<V: VectorArithmetic>(
        value: V, time: TimeInterval, context: inout AnimationContext<V>
    ) -> V? {
        return nil
    }
    
    func shouldMerge<V>(previous: Animation, value: V, time: TimeInterval, context: inout AnimationContext<V>) -> Bool where V : VectorArithmetic {
        return true
    }
}

// the .animation modifier should be:
.animation(progressStarted ? .linear(duration: 5) : .init(Cancel()), value: progressStarted)
```

Importantly, `shouldMerge` returns true, so that SwiftUI merges `Cancel` into the linear animation, hence completing the whole animation immediately.

---

If you want to animate the progress bar *backwards* at a constant speed instead, you can do:

```
// adapted from https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part6/
struct MyLinearState<Value: VectorArithmetic>: AnimationStateKey {
    var from: Value? = nil
    var interruption: TimeInterval? = nil
    
    static var defaultValue: Self { MyLinearState() }
}

extension AnimationContext {
    var myLinearState: MyLinearState<Value> {
        get { state[MyLinearState<Value>.self] }
        set { state[MyLinearState<Value>.self] = newValue }
    }
}

struct MyLinearAnimation: CustomAnimation {
    let speed: TimeInterval
    
    func animate<V: VectorArithmetic>(
        value: V, time: TimeInterval, context: inout AnimationContext<V>
    ) -> V? {
        let distance = sqrt((value - (context.myLinearState.from ?? .zero)).magnitudeSquared)
        let duration = speed * distance
        
        guard time < duration + (context.myLinearState.interruption ?? 0) else { return nil }
        
        
        if let from = context.myLinearState.from, let interruptionTime = context.myLinearState.interruption {
            return from.interpolated(towards: value, amount: (time-interruptionTime)/duration)
        } else {
            return value.scaled(by: time/duration)
        }
    }
    
    func shouldMerge<V>(previous: Animation, value: V, time: TimeInterval, context: inout AnimationContext<V>) -> Bool where V : VectorArithmetic {
        context.myLinearState.from = previous.base.animate(value: value, time: time, context: &context)
        context.myLinearState.interruption = time
        return true
    }
}

// the animation modifier:
.animation(.init(MyLinearAnimation(speed: 5 / 100)), value: progressStarted)
```

Again, return true in `shouldMerge` to prevent both animations from running at the same time.

In `animate`, you just do some simple calculations to figure out where the animatable value should be, given a target value and the current time. This is where you take into account whether the animations has been interrupted before.

Comment: Really great! Thanks a lot. This is the only legit answer I've seen. Many talk about using Transaction, which I have messed with but does not appear to cancel a running animation even with disablesAnimations = true.

Comment: @Oscar Yeah, I think `transaction.disableAnimations = true` doesn't work because the view itself is `Animatable`.

Comment: Bah, I went to integrate this into my project and nope... it's iOS 17 or later. Any similar idea for animation cancellation that'll work back to iOS 15?

Comment: @Oscar Using `.animation(progressStarted ? .linear(duration: 5) : nil, value: progressStarted)` would also stop the animation of the circle, but "progressControl internal percent" would show a negative value for some reason. You can change the `animatableData` setter to something like `percentComplete = newValue < 0 ? 0 : newValue`, but that's kind of scuffed.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using a ridiculously simple solution for iOS 15 & 16: an if statement in my SwiftUI view that checks the "in progress" flag and instantiates a non-animated indicator stuck at 0 if it's false. That flag is observed, so when it changes the view gets rebuilt and then I create one with an animated progress value. Not as cool as your solution, but same visual result in my case.

Comment: Welp, that "simple" solution does not work. Upon instantiation, the value is already at 100%. It never exists at 0, so there's no animation. I guess I could introduce a tiny delay at 0 then change it to 100.

Comment: The delay method works, so I've added that as a workaround for iOS 15 and 16.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround for pre-iOS 17. You have an @State or @StateObject that exposes the on/off condition you want to display progress for. Then create a separate @State to start & stop the animated control

When the in-progress condition changes to true, it will trigger the view to redraw and rebuild; at that time, use an `if` statement to build the progress control with animation. Then wait briefly and then start the animation by flipping that @State to true. If you don't wait, the control will be instantiated with its value already at 100%. Code below, which waits .2 seconds. I don't know what the lowest reliable value would be here. In the example here, `recordingMgr.recording` is the on/off state we want to show progress for:

```
struct RecordingView: View
{
    @StateObject var    recordingMgr = RecordingManager.shared // We watch this obj's "recording" property.
    @State var          countdownActive: Bool = false // starts our animation after a delay

...

var body: some View
{
    VStack
    {
        ZStack
        {
            // To make the progress indicator "cancellable," we have to instantiate it at zero
            // and then wait a fraction of a second to switch the value to 100 percent and start the animation.

            if recordingMgr.recording
            {
                CircularProgressView(foregroundColor: Color.red, percentComplete: countdownActive ? 100 : 0)
                    .animation(.linear(duration: Constants.introTimeLimit), value: countdownActive)
            }
            else
            {
                CircularProgressView(foregroundColor: Color.red, percentComplete: 0)
            }
        }
    }
    .onChange(of: recordingMgr.recording, perform: {newValue in recordingStateChanged(toState: newValue)})
}
```

Then here's the little function that flips the flag to start the progress indicator after a delay:

```
func recordingStateChanged(toState: Bool)
{
    if !toState
    {
        countdownActive = false
    }
    else
    {
        Task
        {
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 200000000)
            countdownActive = true
        }
    }
}
```